# Does boot repair really work?

Tags: boot-repair

I installed Xubuntu 10.04 on a 3-year-old NEC laptop, and it won't boot. Boot repair says it's okay, but it's not.  Here's the link to the [BootInfoScript Output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1107675/)

Comment: Please clarify won't boot. What happens exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works pretty well for the majority of situations, that's what its **Recommended Repair** is aimed at.
In your case, GRUB seems ok, but your BIOS may be limited. I suggest you reinstall Xubuntu, but this time with a separate /boot partition at the start of your disk. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition